# Typescript - Solid.js <select> onchange event: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: typescript, solid-js

In the following example, if I don't do ?. for the event.target.value, typescript has the error `Object is possibly null`. With the ?. I get the error `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'`.

What do I need to do to get the type of the event for the onchange to be correct?

```
import { createSignal } from "solid-js";

export default function Cards() {
  const [cellsWide, setCellsWide] = createSignal(0);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <select
          name="cellsWide"
          onChange={(e: Event) => {
            console.log(e?.target?.value);
          }}
        >
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>This is where cards goes - {cellsWide()}</div>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The event handler should look like this:

```js
<select
  name="cellsWide"
  onChange={(e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
  }}
>
```

The difference between `target` and `currentTarget` is explained [on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget). `target` is the element that triggered the event, `currentTarget` is the element the handler is on. This means that strictly speaking, `target` might not be the element you defined the handler on, it might not even be an `HTMLElement`. Using `currentTarget` is therefore the safe alternative.

Comment: Additionally the Typescript guide in the Solid docs touches on this: https://www.solidjs.com/guides/typescript#event-handlers